google chrome driver findElement not working on M1?
We use google chrome driver in our selenium tests (language clojure).
(-> driver
    (try
          (.findElement (By/id "my-text-input"))
            (catch Exception ex
              (log/errorf ex " error caught!!"))))

However, I got the error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: findElement for class org.openqa.selenium.By$ById
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField(Reflector.java:271)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:315)
    at com.my.company$connect$fn__15343.invoke(selenium.clj:50)
    at com.my.company.selenium$connect.invokeStatic(selenium.clj:49)
    at com.my.company.selenium$connect.invoke(selenium.clj:29)

Note that this issue seems only occur on Mac chips as far as I know, cause my teammates who got a intel processor doesn't see the error.

The code doesn't make much sense.
The -> threading macro doesn't care what the contents of the next form - it just puts its arguments into each other, one by one. So it doesn't care that you use (try (...)) and want to put that driver inside those (...) - it will still put it at the second position so that it becomes (try driver (...)).
That means that you end up calling (.findElement ...) directly on the result of (By/id ...), and that's why you see that error.
You need to change the code so that it becomes (.findElement driver ...).

I don't know anything about Selenium or M1, but the Clojure looks obviously wrong. You've got the nesting of -> and try backwards. The -> form macroexpands to
(try
  driver
  (.findElement (By/id "my-text-input"))
  (catch ...))

i.e., you evaluate the driver for side effects (which it can't have since it's just a variable), then throw it away. Then you call .findElement on the result of By/id, without using the driver at all. Surely what you wanted instead is
(try
  (.findElement driver (By/id "my-text-input"))
  (catch ...))

i.e., calling the .findElement method of the driver, passing it a By/id result. You can just write this directly, of course, but if you prefer the -> style (me too), just put it inside of the try normally:
(try
  (-> driver
      (.findElement ...))
  (catch ...))

Or if you are a maniac you could insist on using -> for the try as well, but you have to write in a pretty weird order (don't do this):
(-> driver
    (.findElement ...)
    (try (catch ...)))

These three options all macroexpand to the same thing.
